# Create Vagrant VM with an alias

Tags: vagrant

I want to create a couple of Vagrant VM's. Most of them could be Ubuntu 16.04. But I want the VM's to be named as `webserver01`, `webserver02` and `webserver03`. Basically I want the `Vagrantfile` for each VM to be inside the directory name I provided above.

Command `vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64` might create a new VM but how do I make sure I create three `webservers{1..3}` as above and run `vagrant up` command from inside that directory?

I want all the VM's to be in a specific directory so I just open CMD inside that directory and run vagrant up from inside them.

Answer (score 0):

you can spawn as many VMs with the help of loops.

> https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/tips.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
 (1..3).each do |i|
   
   config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
     node.vm.provision "shell",
       inline: "echo hello from node #{i}"
   end
 end
end
```

you can access any machine from the cli e.g. from the given example in the link you can control node-1 like

> vagrant up node-1 && vagrant ssh node-1